# NumPy piecewise versus NumPy where

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

In what specific situations would [`np.piecewise`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.piecewise.html) be more convenient (less verbose) or computationally speeder than [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), in evaluating a piecewise function on an array?  I'm having trouble seeing such a case, and I seem to run across piecewise functions being evaluated more often with `where`.

`np.piecewise` seems to be more verbose regardless of number of pieces:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.arange(10, 20, dtype=np.float)

# 2 pieces - piecewise is more verbose
a = np.piecewise(b, [b<14, b>=14], [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x/2])
c = np.where(b>=14, b/2, b ** 2)
print(np.array_equal(a, c))
True

# 3 pieces - piecewise still more verbose (won't it always be?)
d = np.piecewise(b, [b<11, np.logical_and(b>=11, b<14), b>=14], 
                 [1, lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x/2])
e = np.where(b>=14, b/2, np.where(b>=11, b**2, 1))
print(np.array_equal(d, e))
True
```

It is also significantly slower:

```
from timeit import timer
# variables above redefined as callables with no args
print('times:\n a: %d, c: %d, d: %d, e: %d' 
      % (timeit(a), timeit(c), timeit(d), timeit(e)))
times:
 a: 17, c: 4, d: 21, e: 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case it helps you decide, here's what `piecewise` is doing:

```
In [2]: b = np.arange(10,20,dtype=float)
```

define the 2 input lists; note that condition(s) are evaluated now.

```
In [12]: condlist = [b<14, b>=14]
In [13]: condlist
Out[13]: 
[array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool),
 array([False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)]
In [14]: fnlist = [lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x/2]
```

`piecewise` just iterates on the 2 lists, and assigns values to the target array:

```
In [15]: a = np.zeros_like(b)
In [16]: for k in range(len(condlist)):
    ...:     idx = condlist[k]
    ...:     a[idx] = fnlist[k](b[idx])
    ...:     
In [17]: a
Out[17]: 
array([ 100. ,  121. ,  144. ,  169. ,    7. ,    7.5,    8. ,    8.5,
          9. ,    9.5])

In [18]: np.piecewise(b, condlist, fnlist)
Out[18]: 
array([ 100. ,  121. ,  144. ,  169. ,    7. ,    7.5,    8. ,    8.5,
          9. ,    9.5])
```

This pair of `where` is similar, except the the `fnlist` calls are applied to the whole of `b` rather than a subset.  In simple calculations like this it probably doesn't make much difference.

```
In [21]: a = np.where(condlist[0], fnlist[0](b),0)
In [22]: a = np.where(condlist[1], fnlist[1](b),a)
In [23]: a
Out[23]: 
array([ 100. ,  121. ,  144. ,  169. ,    7. ,    7.5,    8. ,    8.5,
          9. ,    9.5])
```

In some cases it is wrong to evaluate a function over the whole range of `b` values - for example if it involves division by 0.  The selective evaluation  of piecewise would be better.

Verbosity shouldn't be a significant measure.  We've already spent more time typing that question and answers.  In working code, wordy code can be hidden in functions.  Readability is more important in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

`piecewise` is faster, if the calculation is slow, because only the values, that are needed are calculated.

Shorter version:

```
d = np.piecewise(b, [b<11, (b>=11)&(b<14)], [1, lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x/2])
```